# EndpointNotFoundException in WCF + NamedPipes hosted in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I've created a simple code to allow cross-appdomain communication using WCF and NamedPipes. I'm testing the code on my Windows 8.1 and it is causing a EndpointNotFoundException.

Here is my code:

Service Contract

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://PoC.AppDomainWCF")]
    public interface ICrossAppDomainSvc
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool HasPermission(String User, String Permission);
    }
```

Program.cs (WinForms)

```cs
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartService));
            thread.Start();

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static void StartService()
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CrossAppDomainSvc), new Uri[] {
                new Uri("http://localhost:12000/AppDomainWCF/"),
                new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/")
            }))
            {
                var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICrossAppDomainSvc), binding, "CrossAppDomainSvc");

                // Add a MEX endpoint
                //ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                //metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                //metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:12001/AppDomainWCF");
                //host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);

                host.Open();

            }
        }
    }
```

Client code

```cs
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
            ChannelFactory<ICrossAppDomainSvc> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICrossAppDomainSvc>(binding);

            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/CrossAppDomainSvc");

            ICrossAppDomainSvc service = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpointAddress);

            MessageBox.Show(service.HasPermission("Juliano", "XPTO").ToString());
```

The exception is thrown at the service.HasPermission call.

What is wrong with my code?

### UPDATE

As the question has been answered and my proof-of-concept is working, I've created a repository on GitHub to help anyone who needs to allow cross appdomain communication.

[CrossAppDomainWCF sample code](https://github.com/julianonunes/CrossAppDomainWCF)

Comment: The endpoint address in the server `net.pipe://localhost/` has to match the client `net.pipe://localhost/CrossAppDomainSvc`.

Comment: This is the base address only. If I use the same address I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open your ServiceHost and immediately close it. serviceHost.Open() method doesn't block. So your endpoint doesn't exist because host is already closed when you are connecting

Comment: I was also forgetting to set the binding security mode on the client. It should be: 

NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);